# Android gallery nonselected item with no transparency

Tags: android, xml, gallery, statelistdrawable

Is it possible to have all items in the gallery be "solid" with no transparency? I have tried using StateListDrawable, but it still gives the nonselected items a transparency.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_active="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_enabled="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_window_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_pressed="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_active="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_selected="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background" android:state_window_focused="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/card_background"/>

</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with `android:unselectedAlpha="1"` on the gallery xml